# How to print all lemma_names of word without repeating its synonyms and pos_tag more than once in NLTK synsets?

Tags: python, tags, nltk, wordnet, synonym

I'm trying to find a synsets of words. Here's my codes:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk import pos_tag

def getSynonyms(word1):
    synonymList1 = []
    for data1 in word1:
        wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(data1)
        tempList1=[]
        for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
            synLemmas = synset1.lemma_names()
            for i in xrange(len(synLemmas)):
                word = synLemmas[i].replace('_',' ')
                tempList1.append(pos_tag(word.split()))
        synonymList1.append(tempList1)
    return synonymList1

word1 = ['study']

syn1 = getSynonyms(word1)

print syn1
```

and here's the output :

```
[[[(u'survey', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'work', 'NN')], [(u'report', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'written', 'VBN'), (u'report', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'discipline', 'NN')], [(u'subject', 'NN')], [(u'subject', 'JJ'), (u'area', 'NN')], [(u'subject', 'JJ'), (u'field', 'NN')], [(u'field', 'NN')], [(u'field', 'NN'), (u'of', 'IN'), (u'study', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'bailiwick', 'NN')], [(u'sketch', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'cogitation', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'analyze', 'NN')], [(u'analyse', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'examine', 'NN')], [(u'canvass', 'NN')], [(u'canvas', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'consider', 'VB')], [(u'learn', 'NN')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'read', 'NN')], [(u'take', 'VB')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'hit', 'VB'), (u'the', 'DT'), (u'books', 'NNS')], [(u'study', 'NN')], [(u'meditate', 'NN')], [(u'contemplate', 'NN')]]]
```

as we can see, `'study','NN'` appears more than once

how to print only once for each synonyms without repitition?

so each synonyms represented with only one synonym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always appending to the list you have inside the for loop, in the line `tempList1.append(pos_tag(word.split()))`. You should check if the element you are trying to add is there in the list already. Having a simple if statement check should do it.

```
if pos_tag(word.split()) not in tempList1:
   tempList1.append(pos_tag(word.split()))
```

This was an element will not be added twice.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still duplicate

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: here's my output without pos_tag = [[u'survey', u'study', u'work', u'report', u'written report', u'discipline', u'subject', u'subject area', u'subject field', u'field', u'field of study', u'bailiwick', u'sketch', u'cogitation', u'analyze', u'analyse', u'examine', u'canvass', u'canvas', u'consider', u'learn', u'read', u'take', u'hit the books', u'meditate', u'contemplate']]

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to get all synonyms for a word using nltk, this is the fastest implementation I have found so far:

```
def get_word_synonyms(word):
    synonyms = set()
    for ss in nltk.corpus.wordnet.synsets(word):
        synonyms = synonyms.union(ss.lemma_names())
    return synonyms
```

You can then call the `pos_tag` method for each unique synonym, which should be faster. However, bear in mind that the pos_tag of a word in a tokenized text depends on the adjacent words.

Answer (score -1):

syn1 = set(getSynonyms(word1))

Making the returned list into a set will remove duplicates.  I am assuming here that the order is not important since a set does not have a defined order.

Comment: That won't work as getSynonyms() returns a list of list. And list type is not hashable

Comment: `syn1 = set(syn[0] for syn in getSynonyms(word1))` will strip off the list level. But the OP should fix their code at an earlier stage. (Also, `wordnet` has no `synsets()` method so the code in the question doesn't run.)